# Retornar JSON de API com parametro

Tags: java, spring, java-ee, rest, spring-boot

Olá,

tenho um serviço que consome a API Openweather.
Há uma lista de cidades cadastradas na camada de view. Onde é possível ver a previsão do tempo para cada cidade clicando no link 'previsão'.
Ao clicar no em um link, o serviço é chamado e ele recebe o nome da cidade clicada como parametro, pois este nome vai ser parte da URL que possibilita consumir a API e mostrar a previsão do tempo.

Em um primeiro momento havia criado uma função para pegar o nome da cidade e depois chamaria esta função dentro do serviço que executa a rotina de montar a URL e invocar os dados da API a serem exibidos em tela.

Como estava dando erro e não conseguia setar o parametro dentro do método que achava a cidade, acabei colocando tudo dentro do serviço para tentar facilitar, mas cada vez complica mais.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getForecastByCity/{idcidade}")
    public JSONObject getForecastByCity(@PathVariable("idcidade") Long idcidade) {
        ModelAndView mav = new ModelAndView();
        Optional<CityModel> city = openWeatherRepository.findById(idcidade);
        mav.addObject(city.get().getName());


        String uri = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q={name}&units=metric&appid={appid}";
        String APP_ID = "9482c2f0ff66359309fcdb84b04f3152";



        RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
        String result = restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, mav, APP_ID);
        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(result);

        return jo;
    }
```

Tudo muito confuso ainda. 
Parecia mais simples quando li o exercício.

Obrigado!!!!

Comment: Qual erro está acontecendo?

Comment: Wed Oct 16 10:51:00 BRT 2019
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
404 Not Found
org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$NotFound: 404 Not Found

Comment: Eu debuguei, até pega o nome da cidade na base, mas o problema ta na hora de montar a a url e transformar em objeto JSON pra mostrar na tela. O json dessa API tem objetos aninhados então, pelo que eu entendi, obrigatoriamente vou ter que transformar ele em JSONObject

Comment: Você já tentou trocar a variavel `mav` que você usa na chamado do restTemplate: `restTemplate.getForObject(uri, String.class, mav, APP_ID);` por `city.get().getName()`, porque sua URL espera um "name" não um objeto do tipo `ModelAndView`

Answer (score 0):

Você não está passando os parâmetros da url para chamar o serviço. Pode passá-los usando String.format() por exemplo.

```
String APP_ID = "9482c2f0ff66359309fcdb84b04f3152";
String uri = String.format("http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%s&units=metric&appid=%s",city.get().getName() ,APP_ID);
```

Vi que essa Api espera o nome da cidade como parâmetro.

Answer (score 0):

A resposta do Bruno creio que funcionaria, ou você pode tentar assim: 
`String uri = "http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q="+name+"&units=metric&appid="+appid";`
Acho que seria isto.